# Is PHP password_hash() + password_verify() safe today (May 2016)?

Tags: php, performance, security, encryption

So the question is pretty much in the title ^^.

Below is a little php code I did to test performance on my server ( + screenshot of the result ) and also show you how I intend to use very simply password_hash() and password_verify().

I think I will go with PASSWORD_BCRYPT and cost = 11 what do you think ?

```
<?php
$startpage = microtime(true);
$userPassword = "ILike5InchesIceCubes";
echo "<h2>Password we work on :    " . $userPassword . "</h2></br></br>";


echo "<b>password_hash($userPassword, PASSWORD_BCRYPT) :</br></b>";
$start1 = microtime(true);
$hash = password_hash($userPassword, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
echo "Hash is : " . $hash . "</br>";
echo "Encryption took : ". (microtime(true) - $start1) . " seconds </br>";
$start2 = microtime(true);
password_verify($userPassword, $hash);
echo "Password verification took : ". (microtime(true) - $start2) ." seconds </br></br>";

echo "<b>password_hash($userPassword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT) :</br></b>";
$start1 = microtime(true);
$hash = password_hash($userPassword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
echo "Hash is : " . $hash . "</br>";
echo "Encryption took : ". (microtime(true) - $start1) . " seconds </br>";
$start2 = microtime(true);
password_verify($userPassword, $hash);
echo "Password verification took : ". (microtime(true) - $start2) ." seconds </br></br>";

$cost = 4;
do {

        echo "<b>password_hash($userPassword, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, [\"cost\" =>" . $cost . "])</br></b>";
    $start1 = microtime(true);
    $hash = password_hash($userPassword, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ["cost" => $cost]);
        echo "Hash is : " . $hash . "</br>";
        echo "Encryption took : ". (microtime(true) - $start1) ." seconds </br>";
        $start2 = microtime(true);
        password_verify($userPassword, $hash);
        echo "Password verification took : ". (microtime(true) - $start2) ." seconds </br></br>";

        $cost++;

} while ($cost <= 16);
$endpage = microtime(true);

echo "The whole page took : ". ($endpage - $startpage) . " seconds </br>";
?>
```

[image]

Comment: Yes. But go with PASSWORD_DEFAULT, then a server upgrade might upgrade your hash algo at the same time. Its implemented this way to gracefully upgrade the security of the password hashes when a new algo is recommended instead of Bcrypt

Comment: Yes, and go with as high a cost as you can justify

Comment: That is exactly what i thought i was waiting for an answer like yours to confirm. How long does it take to bruteforce my cost=11 actual PASSWORD_DEFAULT with one classic i7 CPU 8G RAM ?

Comment: Even with the default cost (10) a normal length password would take way too long. On consumer hardware you can easily try this yourself though. How many passwords can you try in 1 second? How many combinations are there (charset^length). Then its just simple maths to figure out how many years you need to try all of them

Comment: This is not a complete test. You need a stronger password to test with. It uses no punctuation or special characters. Also, you need to look at the negative time responses (over a network) for the positive ones to have real value here.

Comment: Also, the duration of the test is far too short.

Comment: Anthony Rutledge I am very unsure it is useful isn't password_hash() making it as complex/long to crypt whatever the ( max 72 char) password ?
JimL yeah I did basic calculations that's huge Oo

Comment: All encryption is beatable. Next.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, [`password_hash()`](https://secure.php.net/password_hash) is the way to go. There's a great post over at Security StackExchange with more information [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/49643/78440):

> Using bcrypt is a good start; that's the recommended choice (or at least one of the recommended choices). The [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) seems to indicate that PHP *finally* does things properly. Make sure that your PHP version is at least 5.5.0. Don't try to fiddle with salts: by default, the function will generate a random salt when needed, and that's the right way to do it, so just let it do its job.
>
> You should try to alter the "cost" option as well. For bcrypt, the cost is a value ranging from 4 to 31; each increment means that the password hashing is twice as expensive, both for your server and for the attacker. In practice, you want to make that value as high as can be tolerated, given your server power, average load, peak load, and maximum user patience: this will give you the best security that you can hope for.
>
> (Note that I said "the best", not "good".)
>
> If you want to understand the underlying concepts for good password hashing, and why bcrypt is a good choice, [start here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/31846#31846).

`password_hash()` has been greatly improved in PHP 5.5+, and this, along with `PASSWORD_BCRYPT`, should be a good way to go.